# Android Picasso. Пропорционально изменить рисунок

Tags: android, resize, picasso

Загружаю картинку через интернет.

Некоторые картинки очень большие и быстро съедают память, чтобы этого не происходило я хочу сделать resize картинки.
Но это надо сделать пропорционально, т.е. изначально я знаю только ширину в которую надо вписать картинку, а высоту надо подогнать пропорционально.

Как сделать, если я заранее не знаю ширину и высоту загружаемой картинки, а метод  resize должен получить сразу два параметра.

Comment: Возможно здесь есть ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889735/resize-image-to-full-width-and-variable-height-with-picasso

Answer (score -1):

Достаточно после `resize` использовать `centerCrop`. Попробуйте так:

```
resize( , ).centerCrop()
```